# Return Meteor.http results in method

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a Meteor method that wraps around an http.get. I am trying to return the results from that http.get into the method's return so that I can use the results when I call the method.
I can't make it work though.

Here's my code:

(In shared folder)

```
Meteor.methods({
    getWeather: function(zip) {
        console.log('getting weather');
        var credentials = {
            client_id: "string",
            client_secret: "otherstring"
        }

        var zipcode = zip;

        var weatherUrl = "http://api.aerisapi.com/places/postalcodes/" + zipcode + "?client_id=" + credentials.client_id + "&client_secret=" + credentials.client_secret;

        weather = Meteor.http.get(weatherUrl, function (error, result) {
            if(error) {
                console.log('http get FAILED!');
            }
            else {
                console.log('http get SUCCES');
                if (result.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log('Status code = 200!');
                    console.log(result.content);

                    return result.content;
                }
            }
        });
        return weather;
    }
});
```

For some reason, this does not return the results **even though they exist and the http call works**: *console.log(result.content);* does indeed log the results.

(Client folder)

```
  Meteor.call('getWeather', somezipcode, function(error, results) {
     if (error)
        return alert(error.reason);

     Session.set('weatherResults', results);
  });
```

Of course here, the session variable ends up being empty.
*(Note that this part of the code seems to be fine as it returned appropriately if I hard coded the return with some dummy string in the method.)*

Help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example `Meteor.http.get` is executed asynchronously.

[See docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_call):

**HTTP.call(method, url [, options] [, asyncCallback])**

> On the server, this function can be run either synchronously or
>   asynchronously. If the callback is omitted, it runs synchronously and
>   the results are returned once the request completes successfully. If
>   the request was not successful, an error is thrown

Switch to synchronous mode by removing asyncCallback:

```
try {
  var result = HTTP.get( weatherUrl );
  var weather = result.content;
} catch(e) {
  console.log( "Cannot get weather data...", e );
}
```

Comment: how can this be achieved on the client?

Answer (score 2):

Kuba Wyrobek is correct, but you can also still call `HTTP.get` asynchronously and use a future to stop the method returning until the `get` has responded:

```
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
    getWeather: function(zip) {
        console.log('getting weather');
        var weather = new Future();
        var credentials = {
            client_id: "string",
            client_secret: "otherstring"
        }

        var zipcode = zip;

        var weatherUrl = "http://api.aerisapi.com/places/postalcodes/" + zipcode + "?client_id=" + credentials.client_id + "&client_secret=" + credentials.client_secret;

        HTTP.get(weatherUrl, function (error, result) {
            if(error) {
                console.log('http get FAILED!');
                weather.throw(error);
            }
            else {
                console.log('http get SUCCES');
                if (result.statusCode === 200) {
                    console.log('Status code = 200!');
                    console.log(result.content);

                    weather.return(result);
                }
            }
        });
        weather.wait();
    }
});
```

There's not really much advantage to this method over a synchronous `get` in this case, but if you're ever doing something on the server which can benefit from something like an HTTP call running asynchronously (and thus not blocking the rest of the code in your method), but you still needs to wait for that call to return before the method can, then this is the right solution.  One example would be where you need to execute multiple non-contingent `get`s, which would all have to wait for each other to return one by one if executed synchronously.

More [here](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Async_on_server).

Comment: Is var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'); only a server thing? how do I add this to my Meteor project? I get a 'Npm is not defined' error

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes asynchronous calls are preferable. You can use async/await syntax for that, and you need to promisify `HTTP.get`.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { HTTP } from 'meteor/http';

const httpGetAsync = (url, options) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        HTTP.get(url, options, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });

Meteor.methods({
    async 'test'({ url, options }) {
        try {
            const response = await httpGetAsync(url, options);
            return response;
        } catch (ex) {
            throw new Meteor.Error('some-error', 'An error has happened');
        }
    },
});
```

Notice that meteor `test` method is marked as `async`. This allows using `await` operator inside it with method calls which return `Promise`. Code lines following `await` operators won't be executed until returned promise is resolved. In case the promise is rejected `catch` block will be executed.